# R Script and Library preloading?

Tags: r, shell, preload, rscript

I have created an R script that it needs to load some libraries first.

The problem is that the script needs 1.6 seconds to finish its calculations (measured it many times with Linux command "time") and 0.7 seconds only takes to load the libraries!

The script runs quite often, so the delay for library loading accounts to almost 80% of the real workload!

Is there any way to have the libraries preloaded so that they won't be loaded each time the script runs?

Any other suggestion to bypass this slowness?

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

library(methods, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(MASS, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(RBGL, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(igraph, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(bnlearn, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(gRbase, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(gRain, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
..
..
```

Comment: Vangelis, I am having a similar problem, did you ever use Rserve() as a resident R instance and connecting to it from an R client?

Comment: No, I have not tried it yet. This script was made as a prototype proof-of-concept for a Master thesis, so the speed improvements were not necessary to be made at the moment. It was added to the "Future Work" section that I haven't spent time on yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you turn your script into a package (which you should anyway, in the longer run ...) then you can use `Imports` of just the symbols you need from the packages you use -- which is typically a tad faster than a full load as done by `Depends`.

So the key is to

1. use a package
2. learn about `NAMESPACE`
3. `import` just the symbols you need.

An orthogonal approach would be not to restart and to save that time --- you could use [Rserve](http://rforge.net/Rserve) as a resident R instance and just connect to it with an R client.  Probably more work though...

Comment: That persistent R instance sounds like the way-faster approach, especially in the long run. Just how much worse is it?

Comment: I wonder if you could A) write you functions using the package functions into an environment, B) qualify the name spaces, C) byte compile the function into the environment, D) save the environment and then just load it up each time the script runs? You can attach it to the session to make it the same as having the functions in global?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try your suggestions. I need to read more about NAMESPACE and RServe now as I did not have a clue about them before.

Comment: Years later: Can I use R Studio Server in the same way as Rserve (i.e. a resident R instance with loaded libraries)?